# How can I make an attached gameobject behave correctly on character flip?

Tags: 2d, unity, animation, transformation

I have a character that on start-up is equipped with another gameobject/prefab as a weapon, attaching it to a hand.

```
void Start() 
{
    handFront = transform.Find ("root/Hip/BodyBone/OverArmFrontBone/UnderArmFrontBone/HandFrontBone/HandFrontMount");

    instance = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("VioletClub"), new Vector3(-0.5f,2f,1f), new Quaternion(0f,0f,45f,-45f));
    instance.transform.parent = handFront;
}
```

As long as I move the character in the initial direction (right) the attached object behaves as it should, staying in the hand no matter the animation played. But when I flip the character, the attached object doesn't flip correctly. In the initial position (standing still) it looks correct but when I start to move the character, the item flips and rotates the wrong way. It does not follow the arm movement like it should.

[image: Correctly attached]

This is what I do on flip:

```
void Flip ()
{   
    facingRight = !facingRight;

    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;

}
```

[image: Incorrect]

When I flip the character back to the right again it all work as it should.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried also flipping the children? With something like `foreach(Transform child in transform)`?

Comment: Yes. I have tried flipping the children. That didn't do the trick.

Comment: Perhaps try detaching the children before the flip and reattaching after the flip is done?

Comment: That didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rotate the object 180 degrees on the X-axis instead of using scale for this.

Use: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html